# Ruby/Cucumber Test Initialize

Tags: cucumber

What is the best way to initialize and clean up the state of my application before and after running each scenario in a feature using Cucumber and Ruby?  I am looking for functionality closely related to the way initialize and cleanup works with .NET unit testing.

I was attempting to create an initialize method in my step file, however this is only called once for the entire feature file and not for each scenario.

**Edit:** After speaking with a colleague, I was informed that all of the test initialization is really what you want to be doing in the 'Given' part of your Given-When-Then.  As for test cleanup, this is still open for discussion.

Answer (score 0):

I guess what you want is:

```
 Cucumber::Rails::World.use_transactional_fixtures = true
```

which will rollback all changes made in your test environment, after each scenario

Comment: tends not to work with javascripty drivers, in which case you would need to use something like the database cleaner gem.